# mprotect: how to get the instruction which causes protection violation?

Tags: c++, c, linux, mprotect

I am using mprotect to set some memory pages as write protected. When any writing is tried in that memory region, the program gets a SIGSEGV signal. From the signal handler I know in which memory address the write was tried, but I don't know the way how to find out which instruction causes write protection violation. So inside the signal handler I am thinking of reading the program counter(PC) register to get the faulty instruction. Is there a easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

If you install your signal handler using `sigaction` with the `SA_SIGINFO` flag, the third argument to the signal handler has type `void *` but points to a structure of type `ucontext_t`, which in turn contains a structure of type `mcontext_t`. The contents of `mcontext_t` are implementation-defined and generally cpu-architecture-specific, but this is where you will find the saved program counter.

It's also possible that the compiler's builtins (`__builtin_return_address` with a nonzero argument, I think) along with unwinding tables may be able to trace across the signal handler. While this is in some ways more general (it's not visibly cpu-arch-specific), I think it's also more fragile, and whether it actually works may be cpu-arch- and ABI-specific.